# Need help importing a java project into Eclipse

Tags: java

I've read and tried many threads here but I'm as yet unsuccessful.

I have a fairly extensive open source java project that I wanna customize for some specific needs.....pretty much a noob at java & eclipse (though some development chops)

I have eclipse Indigo ver 1.

Based on my other little tests, the import source directory structure is:

> Project_dir
>      src_dir
>      bin_dir
>      some-other-dirs
>      several .java files

Seems like this is the correct directory to show as root in the import process, but I get no packages (let alone types) etc. 
  Could somebody link me to a "101" on getting the project imported so I can find the Main and get on with some analysis?
....or maybe 'splain import steps to me in very rudimentary terms?

Comment: Do you try to import project created in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the 'New Java Project' dialogue, set the path to the project's root, and adapt the source and binary folders accordingly (usually a source folder is named 'src', a binary folder 'bin' in eclipse).

Comment: Well....I'm getting there...I monkeyed around with the New JavaProject Dialog, got the path to the top of the source. Packages and types are now visible. Thanks